# Question on Commuting Operators

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose V is a finite-dimensional complex vector space and S,T ∈ L(V) commute. Prove that there exist a, b ∈ C such that range(S − a) + range(T − b) ≠ V. How would I write out the solution to this question? I can't seem to find a contradiction if I assume the negation of the statement.I don't know how to next proceed other than trying to conclude the sum is a direct sum.

Comment: What do you mean, assume the negation of the statement? Edit your post to include precisely what you’re assuming and trying to prove.

Comment: I tried proving by contradiction, ie assuming that "for all a, b in C range(S-aI) + range(T-bI) = V.

Comment: OK. What do you know is true as a consequence of $ST=TS$?

Comment: That S and T are simultaenously diagonalizable and E(a, S) is invariant under E(b,T), but I don't know that a and b are eigenvalues

Comment: What is $E(a,S)$ and $E(b,T)$? I haven't seen this notation before.

Comment: eigenspace of S with eigenvalue a

Comment: “For all $a,b$” …. So you can choose them to be whatever you want .

Comment: So, can I let a and b be eigenvectors of S and T respectively, then S-aI = 0 and similarly T-bI = 0. Not sure what to do now...do I say this is a contradiction since there isnt a unique representation of 0?

Answer (score 2):

We use Theorem 5.80 of [Linear Algebra Done Right](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-031-41026-0.pdf):

> Suppose $V$ is a fnite-dimensional complex vector space and $S, T$ are commuting operators on $V$. Then there is a basis of $V$ with respect to which both $S$ and $T$ have upper-triangular matrices.

Let $\vec{v}_1,\dots,\vec{v}_n$ be the basis from Theorem 5.80, and let $M_S, M_T$ be the upper triangular matrices representing $S$ and $T$, respectively, in this basis.

Let $n=\mathrm{dim}(V)$. Then, $M_S, M_T$ are $n\times n$ matrices. Let $a=(M_S)_{n,n}$ and $b=(M_T)_{n,n}$. In other words, $a$ and $b$ are the lower-right corner entries of $M_S$ and $M_T$. Then, consider $S-aI$ and $T-bI$. The matrices of these operators in the basis $\vec{v}_1,\dots,\vec{v}_n$ are $M_S-aI_n$ and $M_T-bI_n$. Because of how $a$ and $b$ were chosen, both of these matrices have a $0$ in their lower-right corner entry. Therefore, since $M_S-aI_n$ and $M_T-bI_n$ are both upper triangular matrices, all the entries in their bottom row is $0$.

Thus, if one applies the matrix $M_S-aI_n$ to any vector, the resulting vector will have a last entry of $0$. Since this is under the representation of $\vec{v}_1,\dots,\vec{v}_n$, this means that if one applies the operator $S-aI$ to any element of $V$, the resulting element will be of the form
$$
c_1\vec{v}_1+c_2\vec{v}_2+\cdots+c_{n-1}\vec{v}_{n-1}+0\vec{v}_n
$$
In other words, the coefficient of $\vec{v}_n$ will be $0$, so the resulting vector will be a linear combination of just $\vec{v}_1,\dots,\vec{v}_{n-1}$. Thus, $\mathrm{range}(S-aI)$ is a subspace of $\mathrm{span}(\vec{v}_1,\dots,\vec{v}_{n-1})$.

Now, try to make the same argument of $\mathrm{range}(T-bI)$. Then, what can we say about $\mathrm{range}(S-aI)+\mathrm{range}(T-bI)$?

Comment: range(S-aI) + range(T-bI) is a direct sum? Thus there's a unique representation of 0?

Comment: Here is another hint: Prove $\mathrm{range}(S-aI)$ is a subspace of $\text{span}(\{\vec{v}_2,\dots,\vec{v}_n\})$. Do the same with $\mathrm{range}(T-bI)$.

Comment: I'm having trouble putting it all together.

Comment: I don't think such a basis exists. Take any non-diagonalizable matrix $M$ and the zero matrix, they do commute, but that does not imply that $M$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven My bad, I was going off OP's comment that commuting matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable but of course, this is not right, it should be simultaneously triagonalizable. However, a similar argument holds, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @TheAlgebraist My second hint (i.e. $\mathrm{range}(S-aI)$ is a subspace of $\mathrm{span}(\{\vec{v}_2,\dots,\vec{v}_n\})$) was not right because of the diagonalizable vs triagonalizable mixup, I'm going to update my answer to be more in-depth once I fix this.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Based on the book we are using, "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler (fourth edition) Theorem 5.76 of chapter 5E, simultaneously diagnoalizability is equivalent to two operators being commutative. Also, triagonalizability was not mentioned in class. Thanks again for your help : D

Comment: @TheAlgebraist Thanks for sharing this book. I tried to put my answer in terms of the theorems your book uses. I didn't give the full answer, but I think this is a pretty substantial hint, I wanted my answer to be more detailed because of the earlier confusion.

Comment: Great answer! Hope it gets some more upvotes.